# What does へろへろぷ mean?

Tags: onomatopoeia

I know what へろへろ means "spineless" or "limp", but what is へろへろぷ?

Context - これならソラリスの連中だって、
一擊で、へろへろぷ～、ですよ！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many characters in manga and anime have their own unique way of talking, such as adding words and sounds to the end of words and sentences. I think this is one of those cases, both because of the sentence itself and because of the added "～".

Essentially it's just へろへろ (力のないさま, powerless), which roughly translates as "With this, even the Solaris gang is going to be rendered useless in one attack" in this case.